# Symfony Doctrine Migration $connection has no rights

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I need to do a Data Migration along side a schema migration. I am using the `preUp()` and `postUp()` functions to fetch data, apply schema migration and then update the new columns with some old data.

Since I am going to touch at least 6000 records I wanted to use raw queries. I don't have any dependency from the ContainerAwareInterface. On my local copy I do something like:

```
$SQL = "SELECT column FROM table;";
$statement = $this->connection->prepare($SQL);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(); 
//continue with $results etc
```

This is running fine. When I try to run this migration on prod I get the message:

```
Migration 20161117165412 failed during Pre-Checks. Error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'valid_username'@'valid_host' for table 'table'
```

The application has one defined connection/entity manager and the site is working fine. I can't really understand what may be influencing here? Some config I am sure, but I ran out of ideas.

I have checked the privileges set in the mysql.user and all privileges for 'valid_username' are set to N, which is strange because I would expect the  application also to fail on read privileges.

Comment: The credentals should be set in the `$this->connection` - where does it come from?

Comment: It is a symfony project, normally the credentials are in the parameters.yml file

Comment: I meant the connection object - you said you don't have dependency from ContainerAwareInterface, so where does it come from?

Comment: It is directly accessible inside the Migrations class. It represents a Doctrine DBAL Connection.

Comment: So your class uses `Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Migration` or `Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration`? I understand, that there is DBAL connection available, but this dependency must be provided from somwhere - for example, if you create Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Migration object, you have to provide Connection to it's construct method and I'm asking where the Connection dependency comes from if it's not from the container.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no dependency from ContainerAwareInterface, then Symfony's DBAL connection that is defined in parameters.yml isn't available. For example check the `CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand` as it gets the connection from the container.

I assume that you have the migration class inherited from `Symfony\Component\Console\Command`, so the easiest possible solution would be to inherit the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand` and the container, resp. the default connection will be accessible.

The another solution would be to create own `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` object which takes DB connection params within it's contruct method.